# Formulating a universal property for an inclusion map

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, universal-property

Let $B$ be a subset of the codomain of $f : X \to Y$ that contains $f(X)$. Formulate the universal property satisfied by the inclusion map $i : B \to Y$ that characterizes it up to isomorphism among all injective maps into $Y$ whose image contains $f(X)$.

I have been wondering how the universal property and the "isomorphism" should be defined here. One attempt is to define the universal property satisfied by $i$ as the following: there exists a unique map $g: X \to B$ such that $f = i \circ g$. However, this allows a lot of maps $i':B' \to Y$ to be considered isomorphic to $i$, even if the domain of $i'$, $B'$, is not the same size as $B$. Moreover, $i$ and $i'$ can have different images in this sense, which makes it harder to define an isomorphism.

I'd appreciate it if someone could guide me on defining a universal property.

Comment: Are you sure you have written the statement correctly?  As written it doesn't make much sense--$B$ is not uniquely determined by the given information, so you can't specify a universal property for it (unless you use something tautological that refers to $B$ itself).

Comment: I've checked that the statement is surely what I met in an exercise. I believe that it's OK here to use something about _B_ itself when we claim a universal property--like what we did when claiming universal properties for canonical projections, where we describe the universal property of a canonical projection  _p_ in this way: for any map _f_ : _X_ → _Y_ that is constant on the fibers of _p_ : _X_ → _B_, there exists a unique map _g_ : _B_ → _Y_ such that _f_ = _g _ ∘ _p_.

Comment: Is it possible that the exercise asks for a universal property of the inclusion $f(X) \hookrightarrow Y$ ?